Mocking class and companion using mockito
Hypothetical example -
  class ProxyBank {
        def accountName( data : Int) : String = {
        }
    }
    object ProxyBank {
       def getShortAccountName(proxy :ProxyBank ) : String = {
            proxy.accountName() }
   }


class ProxyBankOps{
     
      def getDealingBank( p: ProxyBank) : String ={
          ProxyBank.getShortAccountName(p) }
}

The objective is to test ProxyBankOps.getDealingBank passing in a mock ProxyBank class.
For this I would need to mock the function getShortAccountName in OBJECT ProxyBank.
How do I mock this - given that I cannot change the class hierarchy.

What did you try so far? Any issue you got? Look's like your code is already structured to easily inject a mock value instead of a real one.

Am getting a error when I try to mock the object(not class) ProxyBank

A few things: 1/ you cannot mock objects, they are singletons by definition (well you can with some more magic but it's discouraged by design and for a reason) 2/ what's the point of mocking the object? If you do so, you're "micro-testing" getDealingBank only, you could implement anything in getShortAccountName, it won't be tested. You're also assuming how the method is implemented which you should not know beforehand. 3/ Said differently, I think your need to mock the object highlights either a bad code design (assuming your example here is over simplified) or bad test practices.

There's no point in mocking ProxyBankOps - that's the component you're testing, it's the ProxyBank you want to mock.
